# passing Array by reference perl

Tags: arrays, perl, pass-by-reference

The problem with code is petlist2_out has last lines of petlist1_out when inputfile1 has more lines  than inputfile2. it looks like array passed by reference is to function and copied back is keeping older array content. Please help. the code is working perfectly for all other cases. i am not sure on how to clean the arrays and varaibles other than using undef. When using references how to avoid using same location when function is called multiple times?

i am not a professional in Perl coding.

```
use File::Basename;

#use warnings;
if ($#ARGV != 1 ) 
     {
     print "usage: sort_petlist_extract.pl old-petlist new-petlist";
    exit;
     }

print "\n******    Reading petlist .....\n";

$inputfile1 = shift(@ARGV);                     #get text based IN filename
$inputfile2 = shift(@ARGV);                     #get text based IN filename

my $result   = dirname $inputfile2;
print $result;
#my $filename = basename $filespec;

#$result = 'C:\\temp\\';

#my $inputfile=$ARGV[0];

open(log_file, "> ".$result.'\\'."debug.log");
open(diff_rpt_file, "> ".$result.'\\'."diff_report.txt");

print log_file  $inputfile1."\n";
print  log_file $inputfile2."\n";

open(petlist1, "< $inputfile1") or die "\nCouldn't open input file\n";
my @input_lines1 = <petlist1>;
close petlist1;
chomp @input_lines1;
#foreach(@input_lines1){print log_file $_."\n";}
my($petlist1_2d_ref)=extract_petlist_file(\@input_lines1);
my %petArray1 = %{$petlist1_2d_ref};
undef @input_lines1;
print log_file $petArray1_ref ."\n";
print scalar keys %petArray1;
open(petlist1_out, "> ".$result.'\\'."petlist1_out.txt");       
#just test a display
 for($i=0;$i<(scalar keys %petArray1);$i++)#just a display
     {
     print petlist1_out "${$petArray1{$i}}[0] \t ${$petArray1{$i}}[1] \n";
     }
close petlist1_out;
undef %petArray1;
print log_file "###############################################################################first file copied to array#######################################\n";
print "####################first file copied to array########################\n";



open(petlist2, "< $inputfile2") or die "\nCouldn't open input file\n";  
my @input_lines2 = <petlist2>;
close petlist2;
chomp @input_lines2;
#foreach(@input_lines2){print log_file $_."\n";}
undef $petlist2_2d_ref;
my($petlist2_2d_ref)=extract_petlist_file(\@input_lines2);
my %petArray2 = %{$petlist2_2d_ref};
#my($page_petname)=extract_page_petname(\@input_lines2);### page number extracttion
undef @input_lines2;
print log_file $petArray2_ref."\n";
print scalar keys %petArray2;
open(petlist2_out, "> ".$result.'\\'."petlist2_out.txt");
#just test a display
 for($i=0;$i<(scalar keys %petArray2);$i++)#just a display
     {
     print petlist2_out "${$petArray2{$i}}[0] \t ${$petArray2{$i}}[1] \n";
     }
close petlist2_out; 
print log_file "###############################################################################second file copied to array #######################################\n";
print "####################second file copied to array ######################\n";



####################### sub routines
sub extract_petlist_file
{
undef $arr1;
my $arr1=$_[0];
undef @petlist;
my @petlist=@$arr1;
#foreach(@petlist){print log_file $_."\n";}
my $temp1='';
my $temp2='';
undef @temp;#clear 1D array
my @temp;
undef $_petArray;
my $_petArray;
undef $i;
print log_file scalar @petlist."\n";
my $k=0;
my $pattern1='PET_NAME';

for(my $i=0;$i<(scalar @petlist);$i++)
        {
#print "$i\n";
#print log_file $_;
        $_=$petlist[$i];

        if ((m/$pattern1/) && $combine_flag eq 0)# first time ever in the loop
                    {


                    }


        }

#store the last pet connection to array
@temp=($temp1,$temp2); 
$_petArray{$k}=[@temp];     
undef @temp;
undef $temp1;
undef $temp2;       


return \%_petArray;
}
```

Comment: Start with `use strict;` and `use warnings;` along with a tool like Perl Tidy to fix your indentation.

Comment: Also start by adding a bit of whitespace and cleaning up the indentation :-)

Comment: @Quentin tidy failed to make it tidy. I will try other ways... I need to do manually as commented by Dave cross

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. And stop cluttering your code with attempts to clear your vars. In particular, `undef $var; my $var` makes no sense. It clears an (unused) package var named `$var`, then creates a new completely unrelated variable with the same name.

Comment: @ikegami thanks for the suggestions.. The undef was used as an attempt to clear variable to avoid any copies. The above code was part of a big code which I did when I started perl coding as a hobby 5 years ago. After putting strict for the complete code and fixing them all, the code went to infinite loop. Any way this snippet works as intented now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the guidance. The strict and warnings helped. The actual issue was "my $_petArray;" had to be "my %_petArray;". I was using it as a variable instead of declaring as array.

Comment: *I was using it as a variable instead of declaring as array.* Er... that makes no sense. What (I think) you mean is that you were declaring it as a scalar variable, but you should have declared it as a hash variable.